# Compiler Error: 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\014679fc\1b393534\App_Web_glpoum5i.dll' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, metadata

I'm getting this compilation error again and again. i'm not able to resolve it permanently.

for debugging this error i clean the solution and rebuild the solution, sometimes it's working and sometimes it's again showing same compilation error.

please tell me the permanent solution for this problem.

**Server Error in '/' Application.**

---

```
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\014679fc\1b393534\App_Web_glpoum5i.dll' could not be found
```

Comment: try to close and reopen your visual studio,

Comment: when i reopened visual studio, it work's after 5 min's if i change anything in code, again compilation error occur's..

Comment: Change the dll reference to any other places , may be the temp files folder will cleared after compiling time .  :(

Comment: how to change that dll reference.....?

Comment: please give replay..

Comment: I cleaned the solution and rebuilt it, and that solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer for this please open you web.config file and add below two setting add in the compilation tag

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="false" batch="false">
```

Keep coidng, Also i tried following things when i get the same error in my application which i tried to host in the server

1. Click Start, click Run, type iisreset /stop, and then click OK.
2. Open the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files directory.
3. Delete all files and all folders in the directory that you located in step
4. Click Start, click Run, type iisreset /start, and then click OK.
5. Do a build again and then try to access your site.

Comment: Don't add debug="false" in development environment.